# Constructing a table showing a directory listing works locally but not remotely

Tags: php

I cannot get this to produce what I want server side, which supports PHP, because I can get PHP pages to echo and stuff. But locally it does exactly what I expect it to do. This is of course example code I found lying around on the internet that I modified to look for my specific directory, that is the only thing I changed.

It is supposed to check a directory for .html files and construct a table with each file in the table. It does this locally but on the remote server I'm trying to host the code on, just produces a blank page.

```
<?php
  $directory = "/pages/";
  $contents = scandir($directory);
    if ($contents) {
       foreach($contents as $key => $value) {
             if ($value == "." || $value == "..") {
                unset($key);
             }
       }
    }
        echo "<ul>";
    foreach($contents as $k => $v) {
      echo "<li><a href=\"$directory/" . $v . "\">link text</a></li>";
    }
        echo "</ul>";

?>
```

Comment: *"I cannot get this to produce what I want server side ... but locally it does exactly what I expect it to do."* which is what? what is it that your getting on the server which isn't occurring locally?

Comment: I would suggest adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of the page and see if there is any output from that.

Comment: @l'L'l Thank you. This outlined what was wrong which has been fixed and now works. I will keep this in mind from now on as I am 100% new to PHP

Answer (score 0):

User ***l'L'l*** pointed me in the right direction. `error_reporting(E_ALL);` helped me figure out what was wrong. the directory was a bit more complicated because i am using a subdomain for testing. and thought all i needed was "/pages/" as the directory.